# Which document class / package was used to typset this CV?

Tags: packages, document-classes

Could somebody point me to the appropriate LaTeX document class / package which was used to create this [CV](http://predrag.freeshell.org/portfolio/CV.pdf) file? I know that this is border line acceptable question but I really like to reproduce the source code.

Edit: I linked my new CV instead of the one I tried to reverse engineer.

Comment: The document properties/metadata are your friend: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fquds.png

Comment: Voting to close as _too localized_ ... if you think your question is borderline acceptable, try asking in [chat] first; I think _too localized_ issues are more welcome there. I thought we had a _Which document class?_ catch-all question somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @doncherry Thanks for the help! Please close the post. I could delete it but I still think some people will find it useful.

Comment: You're welcome `:)`. Yes, I think we can keep it. Btw, you can also cast your close vote on your own question. Also, could you add something like an anonymized (black bars/blurred) screen shot of part of the document to your question to illustrate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was made using [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv). Here's an extract from an [example template](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.pdf):

[image]

A snazzy addition to `moderncv` is [`moderntimeline`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline), although it doesn't seem to be used in the example you posted.