# Generating a software report using TeX

Tags: document-classes

I would like to generate a software report similar to the ones shown below:
[image]
[image]

What is the best `documentclass` to use for such a report? The standard `article` documentclass seems to be specifically targeted for really academic type reports. I'm looking for something a bit more functional where I can really control the space layout and where images and text goes.

If the `article` can achieve something like this, please let me know what I packages or libraries I need to implement for me to be able to do so. Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

To address the comment below I will try to make the question more specific:

- What have you tried so far? I have researched different documentclasses to see if they suit my need. The closest [one I found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82803/which-document-class-package-was-used-to-typset-this-cv) is better suited for resumes and not really suited to what I am trying to do
- What kind of data do you want to present?
  Please see an image below of what I am trying to achieve

[image]

- What layout specs are you going to implement?
  I hope to make this an automatically generated report which will present a wide variety of plots and tables in a homogeneous manner. Therefore I will need quite a bit of control with regards to the margins, plot sizes, etc.

Comment: This question seems far too broad. What have you tried so far? What kind of data do you want to present? What layout specifications are you going to implement? So please clarify your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is very generic, so only generic answers are possible. I suggest asking quite specific and detailed questions for problems as they arise. Any document class should be fine. For margins, try the [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. For plots, probably [pgfplots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) and [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz), although you may want to try [pstricks](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks). Tables, my favourite is [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). Also, look at [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor).

Comment: Ultimately the document class is not that relevant; `article` will work. What you need to focus on is what are the logical pieces of such a report and then design markup macros/environments for them.  Ultimately this is the kind of thing that would probably be best turned into a custom class of its own.